# How to update a table complete from one server to another and add to a second server when the field is added in the first?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert-update

Well I have the following table in 2 servers the server 1 must send all this information straight to the server 2 for example "id", "username", "iddns", "dns", "ipdnstipo" and "ipdns" fields just like it is and if I for example increase the "stock" field it is also added to the server 2.

I know I'm asking too much, if it only update from one server to another I am already very happy.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trad` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`iddns` int(11) NOT NULL,
`dns` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ipdnstipo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`ipdns` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `trad` (`id`, `username`, `iddns`, `dns`, `ipdnstipo`, `ipdns`) VALUES
(1, 'master', 0, 'exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
(1, 'master', 1, 'dns1.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
(1, 'master', 2, 'dns2.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
(1, 'master', 3, 'dns3.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
(1, 'master', 4, 'dns4.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
(1, 'master', 5, 'dns5.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
(1, 'master', 6, 'dns6.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
(1, 'master', 7, 'dns7.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
(1, 'master', 8, 'dns8.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
(1, 'master', 9, 'dns9.exemplo.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
(1, 'master', 100, 'exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
(1, 'master', 1000, 'exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
(1, 'master', 10000, 'exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
(1, 'master', 101, 'dns1.exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
(1, 'master', 102, 'dns2.exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
(1, 'master', 103, 'dns3.exemplo1.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
(1, 'master', 200, 'exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
(1, 'master', 2000, 'exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
(1, 'master', 20000, 'exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103'),
(1, 'master', 201, 'dns1.exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.101'),
(1, 'master', 202, 'dns2.exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.102'),
(1, 'master', 203, 'dns3.exemplo2.com.', 'A', '10.0.0.103');
```

Only could do this with my research but not working.

```
<?PHP
$db_host1     = "10.0.0.101";
$db_user1     = "dns";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "dns";
$db_connect1  = mysqli_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1, $db_name1);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$db_host2     = "10.0.0.102";
$db_user2     = "dns";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "dns";
$db_connect2  = mysqli_connect($db_host2, $db_user2, $db_password2, $db_name2);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query(
$db_connect1,
"SELECT * FROM trad"
);

$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
$trad = $row;
mysqli_query(
$db_connect2,
"INSERT INTO trad"
);
}
mysqli_close($db_connect1);
mysqli_close($db_connect2);
?>
```

Comment: Is this a one time thing, or do you need to keep the databases in sync constantly?

Comment: Not every bank are only 2 or 3 tables that need to be synchronized

Comment: I would recommend you use MySQL replication and just limit it to specific tables, so that you don't have to do any of these scripts and run them manually or on intervals. This script won't give you perfect copies of the tables, because it doesn't cover removing deleted rows or updating existing rows.